# This random variable $Z$ seems to have the same distribution as $\min{X,Y}$ as $|X-Y|$, for $X,Y \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, mathematical-modeling, uniform-distribution

Based on these (but I hope this is self-contained):

[Why does $\min(X,Y)$ and $|X-Y|$ have the same distribution when $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832052/why-does-minx-y-and-x-y-have-the-same-distribution-when-x-y-sim-u0-1)

[Random points on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058707/random-points-on-a-circle)

For $X,Y \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$, $\min\{X,Y\}$ and $|X-Y|$ have the same distribution, as explained intuitively in the 1st question. Apparently, for this random variable $Z$ described in the 2nd question, $Z$ also has the same distribution as $\min\{X,Y\}$ and $|X-Y|$. $Z$ is described as

> Suppose 3 (distinct) points are uniformly and independently distributed on a circle of unit length (smaller than a unit circle!). This is really circle and not disc. Call one of these points $B$. Let $Z$ be the random variable denoting the distance of the point $B$ to its neighbour in the anti-clockwise direction.

Of course the precise answer to this is that they all have pdf $f_Z(z) = 2(1-z)1_{z \in (0,1)}$. But I'm wondering here if $Z$ is actually the absolute difference or minimum or 2 iid uniform(0,1) or if $Z$ is [something else altogether](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061227/existence-of-random-variables-d-e-such-that-gd-e-a-where-a-has-the-same).

Comment: $X\sim Y$ doesn't implies that $X=Y$.

Comment: @Surb yeah I know it's like 2 bernoulli's with the same probability parameter $p$ but different spaces. or even the same space like $(0,1)$ but different intervals each like $1_{(0,0.4)}$ or $1_{(0.2,0.6)}$. Just wanted to check here if perhaps $Z$ was like a $\min$ or an absolute value or just really something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe $Z=\min\{X,Y\}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are described in [David K's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4059368/733302):

> Let $X$ be the anticlockwise distance along the circle's circumference from $B$ to $A$.
> Let $Y$ be the anticlockwise distance from $B$ to $C$.

> Since the three points are independently uniformly distributed along the circumference of the circle, $X$ and $Y$ are iid variables with uniform distributions on $[0,1).$