# Existence of random variables $D,E$ such that $g(D,E)=A$, where $A$ and $g(B,C)$ are identically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, uniform-distribution

**Questions**:

1. For random variables with $A,B,C$ and some function (probably Borel-measurable and bounded/integrable) $g$, if $A$ and $g(B,C)$ have the same distribution, then does there necessarily exist random variables $D$ and $E$ such that $A=g(D,E)$ (at least almost surely)?
2. If this doesn't work in general, then are there conditions where such $D$ and $E$ will exist?

---

**Context**:

1. Sum of iid Bernoulli is binomial. But also conversely, for every binomial random variable $X$, what I understand is that there exists iid Bernoulli's whose sum equals $X$. Like, not just equal in distribution but really at least almost surely equal. Also, I don't think this is trivial because it's not like binomial distribution's definition necessarily depends on having a definition of bernoulli distribution. Well at least I recall in undergrad that we learned Bernoulli after Binomial.
2. This question ([This random variable $Z$ seems to have the same distribution as $\min{X,Y}$ as $|X-Y|$, for $X,Y \sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,1)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061210/this-random-variable-z-seems-to-have-the-same-distribution-as-minx-y-as)) and that question ([Why does $\min(X,Y)$ and $|X-Y|$ have the same distribution when $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832052/why-does-minx-y-and-x-y-have-the-same-distribution-when-x-y-sim-u0-1)).

For $R=\min\{X,Y\}$ and $Q=|X-Y|$, I was able to find random variables $I,J,G,H$ such that $R=|I-J|$ and $Q=\min\{G,H\}$. However, neither $(I,J)$ nor $(G,H)$ necessarily have the same relationship as $(X,Y)$ (which is that $X$ and $Y$ are iid). Also, each of $I,J,G,H$ isn't necessarily Unif(0,1). I was thinking to ask later on if there were such $(I,J)$ or $(G,H)$, but I wanted to settle the existence of $D,E$ 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is no, at least not in general. The answer to the second question might be a bit more subtle. Of course a necessary and sufficient condition would be that $D,E$ exists and $A=g(D,E)$, but that isn't really useful.

Let me argue why the answer to the first question is no. Consider the probability space $\Omega = \{0,1,2\}$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and the probability measure given by
$$\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) = \begin{cases} \frac14 & ,x=0 \\ \frac12 & ,x=1 \\ \frac14 &,x=2 \end{cases}.$$
Furthermore consider the random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $X(\omega)=\omega$. Clearly $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\mathbb{P}(\{x\})$ for $x=0,1,2$ and therefore $X\sim \operatorname{Binomial}(2,\frac12)$. Now, since our probability space $\Omega$ is quite small, there isn't many ways to construct $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(\frac12)$ variables, in fact there are only 2 ways:
$$Y(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 &,\omega =0,2 \\ 0 &,\omega =1 \end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad Z(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1 &,\omega=1 \\ 0 &,\omega=0,2\end{cases}.$$
Now first of all $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent, since $Z=1-Y$, and furthermore $Y+Z = 1 \neq X$. Hence it is clear that $X$ cannot be written as a sum of $i.i.d.$ $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(\frac12)$ variables.

Comment: thanks! good example. it says on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#cite_ref-20) 'Conversely, any binomial distribution, B(n, p), is the distribution of the sum of n Bernoulli trials, Bernoulli(p), each with the same probability p.' Is this wrong? [this](https://www.statlect.com/probability-distributions/binomial-distribution#hid3) is the source

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon The wiki page says "is the distribution of the sum of n Bernoulli trials..." and is thus underlining the fact, that the result only holds for the distribution, and thus there is nothing wrong with the formulation on the wiki page.

Comment: However it would seem that the statlect page is wrong. The proposition clearly states "if $X$ is binomial, then $X$ is a sum of independent bernoulli trials with parameter $p$", but if you read the proof, then what is actually proved is "if $X$ is a sum of independent bernoulli trials with parameter $p$, then $X$ has a binomial distribution". The statement $p\Rightarrow q$ is simply not the same as $q \Rightarrow p$.

Comment: thanks 1 - re wiki: ok i just figure it gives some motivation for the question 2 - re statlect: ah right yeah i guess

Comment: 'The answer to the second question might be a bit more subtle. Of course a necessary and sufficient condition would be that D,E exists and A=g(D,E), but that isn't really useful.' --> to clarify: is this currently all you have for 2nd question?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes i don't have anything else for question 2 at the moment. I can't really think of any conditions that aren't somewhat trivial. Of course such conditions exist, but i think the question is far too general  to give a short and precise answer to.

Comment: ok thanks. please consider editing some of your last comment into your answer